# What is the purpose of the file named gost.so in the filesystem root?

Tags: root

What is the purpose of the file named `gost.so` in the filesystem root?

I found this rather by accident in the root of my file system tree:

```
drwxr-xr-x  19 root root       4620 Apr 26 20:51 dev
drwxr-xr-x 168 root root      12288 Apr 26 12:49 etc
**-rw-r--r--   1 root root     343464 Nov 30  2021 gost.so**
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root       4096 Apr  4 14:16 home
```

What legitimate purpose does a shared library serve there? I couldn't find anything about it so far.

Comment: All instances of `gost.so` in [the official packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&mode=exactfilename&arch=any&suite=focal&keywords=gost.so) live inside `/usr/lib`. You probably just copied this file there accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ apt-file search gost.so
libengine-gost-openssl1.1: /gost.so
```

Looks like a part of openssl.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for helping me :)
learned about apt-file and installed it right away. Now I can track suspicious files by myself in the future.

On my way to removing it I also learned that OpenSSL seems to have installed it there on purpose, for every application in need of encryption facilities to find it easily. And that's surprisingly a lot of them:

```
  Die folgenden Pakete werden ENTFERNT:
  apport* apport-gtk* apturl* bluez-cups* ca-certificates*
  ca-certificates-java* certbot* cups* cups-browsed* cups-core-drivers*
  cups-daemon* default-jre-headless* hplip* liblwp-protocol-https-perl*
  libnet-dbus-perl* libruby3.0* libwww-perl* libxml-parser-perl*
  libxml-sax-expat-perl* libxml-twig-perl* openjdk-11-jre-headless*
  openshot-qt* openssl* origami-pdf* pdftk* pdftk-java*
  printer-driver-gutenprint* printer-driver-hpcups* printer-driver-splix*
  python3-acme* python3-apport* python3-certbot* python3-certbot-apache*
  python3-certifi* python3-httplib2* python3-launchpadlib*
  python3-lazr.restfulclient* python3-requests* python3-requests-toolbelt*
  python3-software-properties* rake* ruby* ruby-atk* ruby-cairo*
  ruby-cairo-gobject* ruby-colorize* ruby-gdk-pixbuf2* ruby-gio2* ruby-glib2*
  ruby-gobject-introspection* ruby-gtk2* ruby-origami* ruby-pango*
  ruby-pkg-config* ruby-rubygems* ruby3.0* rubygems-integration* snapd*
  software-properties-common* software-properties-gtk* ssh-import-id*
  ssl-cert* testssl.sh* **ubuntu-mate-core* ubuntu-mate-desktop***
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-core* ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk* update-manager*
  update-manager-core* update-notifier* update-notifier-common* x11vnc* xorg*
  xserver-xorg*
```

Since my laptop runs with Ubuntu Mate and my hired virtual server only runs Ubuntu, same version, this even seems to explain the difference in installations.

My conclusion: gost.so didn't get there by accident and truly serves a legitimate purpose.

Again thanks for helping me

Comment: This is incorrect. The `libengine-gost-openssl1.1` package that provides the `gost.so` file does not put it in `/`, you can install it in a clean system and see for yourself. Further, it's not a hard dependency of `openssl`, removing it doesn't cause `openssl` to be removed. Your system seems to be seriously broken.

Comment: @muru On an Ubuntu 22.04 clean VM, the installation of the libengine-gost-openssl1.1 package does put gost.so into the root. The package/file does not even exist in Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: Hmmm, that's interesting - this seems like a clear packaging bug. The package name changes in 23.04 (the 1.1 is dropped) but the package only exists for non-amd64 architectures and the file goes back to the usual location in `/usr/lib` like it was in 20.04. At any rate, it's not a hard dependency of openssl in any version of Ubuntu, and removing it doesn't affect the `openssl` package.